# what is the path one have to follow in order to become Full Stack developer?

Tags: django, web, web-frontend, angular-fullstack, react-fullstack

I am the student of 4th semester in CS dept. so far i have learnt **C++,OOP(java) and data structures(java) currently learning data base.**
I want to be a best full stack developer. but when search for the material to study. I get so many things like there is a **node.js** as well as there is ***Django*** , we have **React** for frontEnd and as well as **Angular** and many others. and when i google for the best path for full stack i get different answers.
and I am afraid for this that what if... what i am learning  today is not going to be useful for me in future.
I am confused by seeing technologies frameworks libraries in order for be a full stack.

I have earn a certificate on web developing by **cs50.** after that  i can make small web application but i have no knowledge of what is happening behind the scene. They also gave the **Introduction of REACT**.
and **currently i am doing courses on JavaScript and next i am thinking to study all this instructed by cs50(David and Brain) deeply so that i can make more elegant and large scale web application.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxQDc.png)

kindly anyone please clear my confusion so that i can do best in my future.

Answer (score 1):

A Full-Stack web developer is a term used for a developer who is an all-rounder. Yes, you have read it correctly; he/she has the skills of a front-end developer and a back-end developer. A Full Stack Developer should also be familiar with various security issues and their solutions. He/She should be experienced enough to understand website design and user experience. Any skill in addition to Front-End and Back-End Development is an advantage for a Full Stack Developer.

Follow the Link for Full Stack Development – Steps to Become a Full Stack Developer -
https://thewebseeker.com/full-stack-developer/